# installing visual studio 2005 in winehq

Tags: testing, permalinks, wine, ubuntu-13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 in this operating system i am want to use Visual studio..
so i ahave installed the Winehq latest version but while i am going to install visual studio 2005 it displays a error..
A trial edition is already installed on this computer.You must uninstall the previous trial before installing another trial edition.  I have tried to install the Software in Windows xp mode and Windows vista mode but not works...  **how can i install it in my Laptop...Please Give a solution**.....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXTtB.jpg
The snapsot is given in this Post letz check this and give a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Copy a mfc42.dll to ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/
I test the mfc42.dll 6.0 is work.
Check this: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=1222